# Problem renewing expired provisioning profiles

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning, adhoc

My Ad-Hoc and Distribution provisioning profiles have expired.

When I click on Renew on the AdHoc/Distribution tab from the Provisioning Portal I get kicked back to the Development Tab.

When I click on the expired provisioning profile from XCode and click on Refresh and log in with my credentials, nothing happens.

How can I renew my provisioning profiles?

Note:
My Distribution Certificate is also expired. iTunes Provisioning Portal gives me the option to revoke it. Do I revoke and recreate a new certificate?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Remove Expired Certificates
2. Recreate Development and Distribution Certificates
3. Delete Development and Distribution Provisioning Profiles
4. Recreate Development and Distribution Provisioning Profiles with new Certificate
5. Delete all old certificates in keychain
6. Install new provisioning profiles in XCode Organizer
7. DONE

Answer (score 5):

I've experienced a similar issue. When trying to renew the expired provisioning profiles in Xcode's Organizer it gave the message "No value was provided for the parameter 'certificatelds'" after hitting the Renew-button.

But instead of recreating the expired provisioning profiles I was able to update them from the iOS Provisioning Portal website as a workaround. From the Distribution tab in the Provisioning section press the Modify button. Type a character the field Profile name and delete it again, so the names stays the same but the Submit button will be enabled. Press Submit.

In Xcode Organizer delete the expired provisioning profile(s) and press Refresh to load the renewed provisioning profile(s).